# Detecting https from HttpContext in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I've inherited a pile of code for a web app which contains oodles of hard-coded paths.  I've been tasked with trying to get it to run using  https://.

Other than detecting "https://" in the URL is there a more inband way to detect that the current context is https?

Looking for something like:

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.***Protocol.ToString()***

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection`

Comment: For .NET Core/6 it is `HttpContext.Request.IsHttps`

Answer (score 13):

The direct answer to your request for something like `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Protocol.ToString()` is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme`, though as Brandon says, in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856274/detecting-https-from-httpcontext-in-net/3856307#3856307)`HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection` is the way to detect use of https as a boolean and likely more appropriate to the problem you give in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to auto redirect to https

```
If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(False) Then
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
End If
```

Comment: Probably for the ".Equals(False)" bit. Though it should work, it doesn't make any sense to write the code that way. Also, you shouldn't use + for string concatenation in VB.

Comment: To make the code more readable in a human way, I would write it like this If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection Then