# What HTTP header does HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection look for?

Tags: asp.net

I assume that HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection in ASP.NET looks at some HTTP Header to determine whether the connection is secure.

Does anyone know which header is it looking at?

Comment: I think it is just checking the protocol (https) but since you are on the server side, maybe its also checking iis configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is checking for the use of SSL (`https://` vs. `http://`). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856274/detecting-https-from-httpcontext-in-net).

Comment: That's not the question i am asking.  I know what this is for but i want to know what HTTP header does ASP.NET look for in the HTTP request to determine which protocol was used.

Comment: You're assuming that it's looking at an HTTP header; what makes you think so? I believe that instead it looks at the scheme, as I mentioned.