# How to detect a website using ssl

Tags: security, ssl

Can anyone show me some example to detect if a website using SSL (.net or php ..), because i want to apply suitable action to these type of website.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856307/761829 in a .NET context.

> You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection`